# proper way to embed arguments to jQuery with html5?

Tags: jquery, html, dom

To avoid excessive `$('#.').click()`-functions, I want to pass arguments in an `li` element.

What would be the proper way in HTML5?

example:

```
<ul>
  <li>I'm clickable<code>method|parm1,parm2</code></li>
....
$('li').click(e) function() {
  //I will read the method and serve...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The

```
<code>
```

tag is there for styling only. You should probably use data attributes like so:

```
<ul>
  <li data-method="method" data-params="parm1,parm2">I'm clickable</li>
   <!--...-->
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider using the `data` attribute.  Take a look at [Embedding Custom Non-Visible Data with Data Attributes](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/elements.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-attributes).  In your case you would do something like:

```
<ul>
  <li data-code="method|parm1,parm2">I'm clickable</li>
  ....

<script>
  $('li').click(function(e) {
    var code = $(e.target).data("code");
    // I will read the method and serve...
```

Comment: I added a link to the w3 spec.

Comment: Regarding W3Shcools link, it's because that link only lists the new elements in HTML5, not new attributes, plus W3Schools, even though the name, is not an official source anyway, and is "not" part of W3C.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `onclick` attribute directly, or the `data` attributes as mentioned in other answers, or even `href="javascript:myFunction(param1, param2);return false;"`, but the idea itself is wrong IMHO. The markup should not contain code. If so many elements have the same kind of effect with variables, use a generic selector to match them all, and use `data` attributes to save the values, and use jQuery to call the code. Your code should be separated from markup.

Example, lets say you want to change the colour of text of a list by clicking one of its links:

*HTML*

```
<ul id="colorChangeDemo">
    <li><a class="color-change" href="#" data-color="#f00">Red</a></li>
    <li><a class="color-change" href="#" data-color="#0f0">Green</a></li>
    <li><a class="color-change" href="#" data-color="#00f">Blue</a></li>
</ul>
```

*JS*

```
$(function() {
    // Note all code is in the same block

    // Note how I cached the things I thought I may need later
    var $colorList = $("#colorChangeDemo");
    var $colorLinks = $colorList.find("a.color-change");

    function changeColor(event) {
        var $colorLink = $(this);
        var color = $colorLink.data("color");
        $colorLinks.css("color", color);
        event.preventDefault();
        return false;
    }

    $colorLinks.click(changeColor); // Can be separate function
});
```

*Live Example:*

http://jsfiddle.net/u6syK/2/

.

Of course there could be exceptions and you may have a good reason to go this path, but it's often a code smell I'd say.

Comment: doesn't onclick smell with html5?

Comment: It does. I was just explaining all the available options. If I'd go the code-within-markup path, I'd use the "href" one personally, but as I mentioned, I don't recommend going this path anyway.